# Short lag when setting label text using storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

In my application, I have a `mainViewController` with some content on it. At some points, I load an overlay view controller from storyboard. The overlay view controller is smaller than the screen and is presented on top of the mainViewController. I initialize it the following way:

```
class MyOverlayViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel!

    static let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "...", bundle: nil)

    // Return a new view controller
    class func newViewControllerWithData(data: AnyObject) -> UIViewController {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyOverlayViewController") as! MyOverlayViewController

        Timing.performAfterDelay(0) {
            vc.titleLabel.text = data[...] // Load title label text
            vc.countLabel.text = data[...] // Load count label text
        }

        return vc
    }
}
```

I cannot set the text of the labels immediately in the method `newViewControllerWithData`, because that produces the following error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.` So the labels are `nil` when accessing them immediately in this method.

It seems like the two label outlets are **not loaded immediately** when the view controller is instantiated from storyboard, because this takes a (very) short time.

Therefore, I use my method `Timing.performAfterDelay(0)` which executes the code after the next run-loop cycle (it starts a timer with duration `0` and executes the code as callback). The code is (I have checked that) executed on the main thread.

**The problem is the following:** 
Sometimes (not always, and not reproducible!), when loading the overlay view controller, for a fraction of a second the labels are **empty** (like I have defined them in storyboard) before they are showing the text.
So the user sees empty labels for a short moment before the actual data is loaded into the labels.

How can I fix this behavior? 
Is it possible somehow to access the outlets immediately after instantiating the view controller from storyboard, without using `Timing.performAfterDelay(0)`?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlets are set *after* view is loaded i.e. when `viewDidLoad` gets called on the view controller. However, calling it directly like `vc.viewDidLoad()` will not work, you have to access the view controller's view like `let dummyVariable = vc.view` instead. Here's the code that force loads the view and then sets the label values.

```
class func newViewControllerWithData(data: AnyObject) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyOverlayViewController") as! MyOverlayViewController
    let _ = vc.view // force load the view
    // now set your outlets as you please
    vc.titleLabel.text = data[...] // Load title label text
    vc.countLabel.text = data[...] // Load count label text
    return vc
}
```

**NOTE:** This is not really a good practice though. *MyOverlayViewController* should be responsible for setting its label values instead of these being set from the outside. You could pass it the required data via a property or argument to a method, etc.

Comment: Your edit does not help me, because even when `MyOverlayViewController` sets its label values itself, it still needs to load its view (like you described in the answer) prior to that.

Comment: actually, I am saying, for example, that you should have passed data to _MyOverlayViewController_ like this: `vc.data = data`, and then in _MyOverlayViewController_'s `viewDidLoad` method, you should have set both the `titleLabel` and `countLabel`. This has the advantage that you don't have to remember to force load the view with `let _ = vc.view`

Comment: Is it better practice to use `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: do it in `viewDidLoad`, that way it doesn't matter if you loaded the view controller from Nib or if you created it programmatically. `viewDidLoad` gets called in both cases.